# Do rogues get sneak attack damage added to attacks made outside their turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, opportunity-attack, sneak-attack

PHB says 'once per turn,' so, it would seem that a Rogue with Sentinel, for example, could "consistently" deal Sneak attack twice per round (whether the enemy triggers an OA or the melee weapon attack provided by the Feat).

So, can rogues deal sneak attack damage with any weapon attack outside their turn? (obv. one that meets the standard requirements--finesse, adv or adj ally)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes!

The verbiage 1/turn definitely allows for the use of Sneak Attack out of turn for the rogue if they somehow get a reaction attack (either granted by an ally or by an opportunity attack).

Note that this basically limits them to 2x per round since you only get one reaction. But yes absolutely. Note that *all* of the normal restrictions on SA apply, they have to have advantage or an adjacent ally, and they have to be attacking with a finesse or ranged weapon.

Answer (score 28):

### Your Rogue can Sneak Attack on an Opportunity Attack.

> **Sneak Attack.** ...Once *per turn,* you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature *you hit with an attack*... [some restrictions may apply]. (PHB p.96, "Sneak Attack")

There are two important phrases in that description I've highlighted.

*Once per turn.* The writers could have said "on your turn." They didn't, so it doesn't have to be *your* turn<sup>*</sup>. Compare, for example, with Reckless Attack (PHB p.48) which says "when you make your first attack on *your* turn.... (emphasis mine)" A Barbarian clearly cannot both Recklessly and Opportunely attack.

*You hit with an attack.* The writers could have said "when you take the Attack action." They didn't, so the attack you make as a reaction (opportunity attack) is viable. Compare, for example, with the Battle Master's various Maneuvers (PHB p.74): some trigger "when you make a melee weapon attack on your turn," some "when you hit a creature with a weapon attack," some "when you take the Attack action." These subtle differences in applicability are ones that the designers are well aware of, and use to balance features.

(Jeremy Crawford also says so, albeit tersely, in this Sage Advice Exchange: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/18/sneak-once-per-turn/. But he didn't need to, since the rules already said as much.)

---

<sup>* - In case there's any confusion, look to PHB p. 189, The Order of Combat: "during a round, each participant in a battle takes a **turn**." So other people's **turn**s are *a* **turn**, meeting the restriction in Sneak Attack.</sup>

Answer (score -19):

You only get one turn per round. A turn is comprised of an action, movement, reaction, free action and bonus action. Sneak attack let's you add bonus damage ONCE per turn. If you decide to use it with your action, bonus action or reaction is up to you. If you decide to use it during your official turn or during someone else's turn (reaction/ready action) it's still used.

More info:

A sneak attack:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll.

A turn:

> A round represents about 6 seconds in the game world. During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn.

Reaction:

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature’s turn, that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.

Comment: it does not specify once per *your turn* it's 1/turn which could indicate another creature's turn. If this answer was correct, Thief's reflexes would not allow for sneak attack on your second turn. Turn != round in this case.

Comment: The reality is we are both right/wrong. It does not indicate another creature's turn as much as it does not indicate your turn. It just says "once per turn" which can be interpreted as once per each creatures turn or once per turn your character has to give. A creature normally has only one turn per round so most of the time turn == round. A 17th level Thief however gets 2. So do other monsters. So the distinction is made. I feel that it's pretty obvious that they don't get sneak attack on someone else turn as well.

Comment: Well looks like I'm wrong. http://community.wizards.com/forum/rules-questions/threads/4112616

Comment: ummmm read all four of those tweets. The multi attacks is like the fighter's multi attack. Not off turn attacks

Comment: I agree Was Eagle. But apparently it's you and me vs the world on this one. :(

Comment: https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/489804409405075459 may help clarify as well. (Though also worth noting that relying on Mearls' twitter is less than good, let me see if Jeremy has commented on this).

Comment: Since I found the thing I was thinking of before, which includes a tweet from Jeremy Crawford on the matter, I'm going to put it here for the future. [Jeremy Crawford on Twitter.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/608079075337330688?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)
Additionally, going to credit @RogueBurger and [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72296/19580) for providing it.