# How does the Savage Attacker feat interact with opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, opportunity-attack

The [Savage Attacker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/savage-attacker) feat (PHB, p. 169) states that you can reroll a melee weapon's damage dice "once per turn".

If I used Savage Attacker on my turn, and then I get an opportunity attack when an enemy moves away from me, can I also use the Savage Attacker feat to reroll my damage on the enemy's turn?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes, you can use it again on someone else's turn

As you note, Savage Attacker can be used to reroll damage "once per turn". In a given round, each creature gets a different turn (PHB p. 189, ["The Order of Combat"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TheOrderofCombat)):

> The game organizes the chaos of combat into a cycle of rounds and turns. A
>   round represents about 6 seconds in the game world. During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn.

Provided the creature is moving on its own turn (not on your turn), you can use this feature again even if you used it during your turn.

This is a very similar reasoning to the [rogue using Sneak Attack outside their turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/do-rogues-get-sneak-attack-damage-added-to-attacks-made-outside-their-turn), as it uses similar wording.

Comment: Note that this is definitely on purpose, not an accident.  The prior version of D&D (4e) had things like rogue sneak attack be once/round, and they later explicitly changed it to once/turn as they felt "being able to be nasty on an opportunity attack" made sense.  This lesson carried forward to 5e.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes you can

Since the Feat allows you to reroll the damage once per turn, you can indeed use it for Opportunity attacks and other attacks multiple times during a round, up to once per turn. You understood the rule correctly.

An interesting consequence is that characters who have access to the Fighter's Action Surge class feature can use it to get a second action, use that action to Ready an Attack action in a manner that triggers quickly after their turn, and get more damage out of their second action this way.

Comment: Note that you can't use Extra Attack when readying, so this move is going to be useful for only a very short amount of time.

Comment: @Erik Not necessarily, the Action surge might be from a multiclass dip from a main class that doesn't have Extra attack. I could see this having a potentially workable synergy with Sneak Attack.