# Crusher and opportunity attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Crusher feat says:

> Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you.

The once per turn means if you have Polearm master and/or you use your reaction to make an opportunity attack would it activate again since it is not on your turn? And Crusher doesn't refer to "Round" instead?

So, you do your normal turn action and proc the Crusher's feat push. And then when you do an opportunity attack will Crusher push 5ft again?

Comment: Possible Duplicate (not voting on it yet): [Do Rogues Get Sneak Attack Damage Added to Attacks Made Outside Their Turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/do-rogues-get-sneak-attack-damage-added-to-attacks-made-outside-their-turn)?

Comment: @goodguy5 The question may be similar but I wouldn't say it's a duplicate even if the same considerations applied (something an answer would need to argue).

Comment: @Anagkai: IMO it would be a duplicate if we retitled the canonical Q&A to "Do once-per-turn effects like Sneak Attack work on attacks made outside your turn?"  Because the key phrasing is "once per turn" without the word "your", as opposed to phrasing like "on each of *your* turns" (zealot barb Divine Fury).  In this case, nothing else in the rest of the wording says anything about how often you can use it, so the same arguments that apply to Sneak Attack apply here, and there's no benefit to having a separate question except as a signpost for searches.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct

## A turn is just one part of a round

The Crusher feat can activate multiple times per round. This is not the only ability to do so (Sneak Attack, for example, also activates on a per-turn basis).